# React Redux State without Actions

Tags: reactjs, redux

I just started learning Redux and I have a question about the logic of the state when I it needs be always updated no matter the action. I ll give an example of what I mean. Let's say I have an initialState `const initialState = { cartItems: [], totalCost: 0, quantity: 0 };`
and a reducer with an action `case actions.ADD_TO_CART:` and I have some logic here to add an item object to the cartItems array.  Then I 'll change the quantity and the totalCost with something like this `quantity: state.cartItems.reduce((a, b) => a + b.quantity, 0),` but I have to do this on every action (remove from cart, increase item's quantity, etc), whats the best way to handle the the quantity and totalCost, values to update at every action?

Comment: Write some middleware to do cross-cutting state updates -> https://redux.js.org/advanced/middleware/

Comment: can you provide maybe an example?

Comment: The onus is on you to provide an example of what you are trying to do, what you have tried: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example